# Date conversion day before

Tags: java, xsd, calendar, jena

Assuming I have this string:

`String date = "18-7-1495"`

I want to define this in Apache Jena as xsd:dateTime

So I did the following:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-MM-yy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(df.parse(date));
x.addProperty(DCTerms.date, model.createTypedLiteral(new XSDDateTime(cal));
```

The problem is that this date is now stored as:

```
dcterms:date            "1495-07-17T23:00:00Z"^^<http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime> ;
```

Why is the date 17 not 18?

Comment: As you can see the time is 23:00:00 in the Z(ulu) timezone (UTC+0). Since you're parsing a date only the time will be assumed to be 00:00:00 but in the system's default timezone, which seems to have an offset of 1 hour. So when converting `1495-07-18T00:00:00+01` to UTC/Zulu you'll get `1495-07-17T23:00:00+0` (or `...Z`).

Comment: Is there a way to avoid this? Can I also change the time zone?

Comment: Well, the easiest way to avoid this would probably be to ditch the old data api and use the new `java.time` one, e.g. `LocalDate.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withZone(timezone))`.

Comment: So this should be used instead of what?

Comment: You'd use the new api instead of `java.util.Date`, `SimpleDateFormat`, `Calendar` etc.

Comment: Have you also thought about the year 1495? At that time, the gregorian calendar was not used at all anywhere in the world. But APIs like `java.time` use the gregorian calendar only.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Does Time4J offer a good solution here? You are right, of course, that using the Proleptic Gregorian Calendar, as java.time does, is not correct here. It seems from [the docs](https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/datatypes/xsd/XSDDateTime.html) that the `XSDDateTime` constructor needs an old-fashioned `Calendar` object.

Comment: @OleV.V. My lib Time4J offers for example the [HistoricCalendar](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/calendar/HistoricCalendar.html) which is based on a configurable [ChronoHistory](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/history/ChronoHistory.html). It can use many variants of Julian to Gregorian calendar switches and also use various definitions of start of New Year.

Answer (score 0):

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat ("dd-mm-yy")

here mm is considered as minutes so to format month you need to use MM. this will solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem occurs when you add the time to your Model: `new XSDDateTime(cal)`.

## Problem

```
String SOURCE = "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#";
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(df.parse("18-7-1495"));

Resource testResource = model.createResource(SOURCE + "test");
testResource.addProperty(DCTerms.date, model.createTypedLiteral(new XSDDateTime(cal)));

model.write(System.out);
```

Output:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#test">
    <j.0:date rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">1495-07-17T23:00:00Z</j.0:date>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

## Solution

```
String SOURCE = "http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#";
Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();

DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy");
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(df.parse("18-7-1495"));

Resource testResource = model.createResource(SOURCE + "test");
testResource.addProperty(DCTerms.date, model.createTypedLiteral(cal.getTime()));

model.write(System.out);
```

Output:

```
<rdf:RDF
    xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
    xmlns:j.0="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" > 
  <rdf:Description rdf:about="http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#test">
    <j.0:date rdf:datatype="java:java.util.Date">Sat Jul 18 00:00:00 CET 1495</j.0:date>
  </rdf:Description>
</rdf:RDF>
```

Comment: Agreed, so I cannot use the xsd:datetime type? This is strange